# Safe Exam Browse Request Hash

Tags: windows, macos, safe-exam-browser

I'm currently doing a audit of some Safe Exam Browser features as part of my master thesis, and I started looking into the browser request hash that is used to ensure that people use the safe exam browser in the LMS our university has opted for. As an attempt I just created my own SEB config file (on my mac), and I managed to compute the correct browser request hash from the key I got from said config file. If I re-open the same file in the SEB config editor it still presents me with the same hash (so I can get it again later).

However, the SEB config file I got from the LMS system we use, when I open that and copy the config key, I am unable to generate the correct browser request hashes (using the same code). Does this has to do with OSX vs Windows somehow? Or is there some other mechanism that I don't know about?

---

Originally asked at the [Safe Exam Browser forums](https://sourceforge.net/p/seb/discussion/3704033/thread/a9342a82/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if your configs are working properly what is the issue?

Comment: My issues is that when I take the seb exam key out of the config file GUI, combine it with a request URL, and then hash it using SHA256, I get something else than what SEB is transmitting during it's requests. I get the correct value if I author the config file myself, but the file I got from the exam website it does not work with.

Comment: @Alxandr have you found the solution? I am struggling with the exact same thing.